# Context Free Grammar - help me understand

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

I'm currently reading the book "Understanding Computation" by Tom Stuart (a wonderful book, by the way - it's taught me a lot and has been an invaluable resource for someone like me who lacks formalized mathematical training but wants to understand Computer Science better.  Highly recommended!) and we are up to the point of talking about Context Free Grammar (CFG).  There is one particular point about CFG's that I haven't been able to develop a sufficient mental model for - let me demonstrate with an example.

The book uses what is intentionally meant to be a very limited CFG example (for simplicity's sake) that can handle only a very rigid subset of the possibilities you might see in a full programming language (the stuff in single quotes represent tokens, the stuff in angle brackets represent symbols):

```
<statement> ::= <while> | <assign>
<while> ::= 'w' '(' <expression> ')' '{' <statement> '}'
<assign> ::= 'v' '=' <expression
<expression> ::= <less-than>
<less-than> ::= <multiply> '<' <less-than> | <multiply>
<multiply> ::= <term> '*' <multiply> | <term>
<term> ::= 'n' | 'v'
```

Here are some examples of how - using my current mental model - I would read some of these aloud:

"A statement can be a while loop OR an assignment"
For the purposes of this limited example, this makes perfect sense to me.

"A term can be either a number literal OR a variable"
Again, given the limited scope, this makes perfect sense to me.

"A multiply can be a term multiplied by another multiply OR a term"
OK, now I am freaking out a bit!  I understand that giving the "out" to allow a less-than to become a multiply is part of the underlying magic that makes this whole thing work (i.e. it is the mechanism by which our non-deterministic push down automaton is able to explore every possible combination), but logically - at least the way I am reading it - I just can't make it make sense.  Why would that "out" (as I call it) not just be pushed up to the previous level - by which I mean:

```
<expression> ::= <less-than> | <multiply>
```

Is there some reason we must check to see if it's a valid less-than first and then only pursue checking to see if its a multiply only if we've established its not a less-than?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write

```
a * b + c
```

Or, for that matter

```
c + a * b
```

You probably meant the sum of c and the product of a and b. If in the first expression you meant the product of a and the sum of b and c, you would have used parentheses:

```
a * (b + c)
```

How do we express this in a CFG?  We need to say that a sum can be a plus sign with a product on each side. But not just a product: it could also be an exponentiation, or a division, or, of course a variable or a number. Or any expression in parentheses.

Also, multiplication and addition are associative, but not all mathematical operators are. For example, 9 - (5 - 2) is different from (9 - 5)  - 2, and by convention 9 - 5 - 2 is considered to mean the second. So a subtraction can have another subtraction on the right, but not on the left (unless surrounded by parentheses.)

A similar observacion applies to comparisons. In the following:

```
a + b < 3 * c
```

the intention is to compare a sun with a product, rather than to do arithmetic on the result of a comparison.

Comment: I think this makes the most sense to me.  In my mind, I'm thinking of this as "exhausting the possibilities in the order of complexity".  e.g. in your `c + a * b`, if our CFG jumps on the first thing it finds to evaluate (`c + a`), we're going to get the wrong answer, so we have to establish that what is on the right-hand side of the `+` token isn't something more complicated than just a simple token.  Only if we've exhausted all those possibilities can we safely assume this is basic `c + a` arithmetic.

Comment: @user3179733: everyone has their own intuitions, of course, so it's not important that yours don't make sense to me. It's not that `a + b` is more complex than `a * b`; it's more that `*` grabs its arguments first (and `<` grabs its arguments last). Anyway, there is nothing inherently left-to-right about CFGs; you can run a CFG in arbitrary order. An unambiguous CFG will always produce the same parse tree, while an ambiguous CFG will produce different parse trees depending on the order you choose to apply its productions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer has to do with a `<less-than>` being nestable. `<less-than>` can be either a (`<multiply>` < `<less-than>`) or simply a `<multiply>`.

That being said, you could theoretically duplicate `| <multiply>` in `<expression>` but it simply becomes redundant. Either way you have to give `<less-than>` an "out" as you describe, when there is no (< `<less-than>`) continuation.

For example, the grammar as defined in the question would be valid for the following:

```
v=n<v
```

You get (if you forgive the XML notation, it was the best I could come up with to illustrate my point):

```
<statement>
    <assign>
        v
        =
        <expression>
            <less-than>
                <multiply><term>n</term></multiply>
                &lt;
                <less-than>
                    <multiply><term>v</term></multiply>
                </less-than>
            </less-than>
        </expression>
    </assign>
</statement>
```

But if you did not define `<less-than>` with `| <multiply>`, the final "v" above (the `<multiply><term>v</term></multiply>`) does not satisfy any definitions in the grammar (and better yet the definition `<less-than>` would never end!)

Comment: I'm not sure how well this jives with what you're saying, but does it have something to do with the compound nature of the individual types of expressions?  A less-than can be made up of a combination of other less-than's, multiply's, and/or term's.  A multiply can only be made up of term's.  A term can only be one of 2 tokens.  I think the machinery - as it parses - has to exhaust the most complex possibility first, followed by the second most complex, etc.  Is that what you were getting at by "nesting"?  (it's possible we're describing the same thing using different verbiage)